# Oracle sql delete on read

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

The question i have is, how can i delete a record on read? I'm using Oracle ond AIX with the Roguewave DB Layer in a c++ application.

I have been searching on google for this answer but there seem only to be the simple examples. Is there a SQL Statement which returns the deleted rows?

This would greatly enhance performance on my application because only 0.1% of the cases will have a need to stay in this table, in other words i will insert 0.1% back into the table.

The only hint i have found is the "Into" clause, i would assume that using delete into would do the job but i have never used it.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8005.htm#i2126877) it is indeed possible to delete and read in one go:

```
DELETE FROM employees
   WHERE job_id = 'SA_REP' 
   AND hire_date + TO_YMINTERVAL('01-00') < SYSDATE 
   RETURNING salary INTO :bnd1;
```

I never used it myself...but you could give it a try.

Comment: I think this is what i like to have syntax wise, it doesn't run at the moment but i will try to make it work

Comment: Good answer. However, this will only work in a stored procedure, will it? Or can you use it directly from e.g. JDBC?

Comment: @sleske: I used the `returning` clause in `select` statements using OCCI without stored procedures and it worked just fine. Since this is a different scenario (other db layer) I can't be sure though.

Comment: It seems that the bnd1 needs to be turned into a rowtab and every single field requires extraction, there seems to be no trivial statement just to return the deleted rows

Comment: Actually you have served me what i asked for, it would have been awesome to have an actual query to return the table but your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no SQL construct to read and delete a row in one go.

You could write a stored procedure which does this, though. Or you could cache the records you have already read in memory (so you do not read them again), then later do a bulk delete (`DELETE FROM table WHERE id in (?)`). That should be faster than many single DELETEs.

Or you might consider a different approach to the problem. Why do you need to delete so many rows on reading them? Are you using a DB table for passing messages? Is there maybe another technology that is more suited to your problem? If you feel you have to work against the established conventions of a technology, that may be an indication that you are not using the right tool for the job...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like building an audit trigger?

[Good description to build an select trigger.](http://technology.amis.nl/2005/09/select-trigger-in-oracle-database-introducing-fine-grained-auditing/)

Creation:

```
begin
  dbms_fga.add_policy
  ( object_schema=>'SCOTT'
  , object_name=>'EMP'
  , policy_name=>'SAL_ACCESS_HANDLED'
  , audit_column => 'SAL'
  , audit_condition => 'SAL>= 1500'
  , handler_schema => 'SCOTT'
  , handler_module => 'AUDIT_HANDLER.HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS'
  );
end;
/
```

Function signature:

```
PROCEDURE HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS
( object_schema VARCHAR2
, object_name VARCHAR2
, policy_name VARCHAR2
);
```

Comment: How would that help OP? Where do the rows get deleted?

Comment: I actually haven't considered triggers as a solution, my assumption was that a trigger works like a fork Select --> Data (fork trigger) --> return Data to application, tell me if my understanding is not correct

Comment: By changing the insert to an delete inside the called procedure? I have to admit that I have not tried if it is possible to modify the table inside the function without firing again - so maybe a check should be added.

Comment: So you would have to parse the statement (get the WHERE clause) and modify it to a DELETE statement and do an execute immediate.